# C - Counter not working

Tags: c, string, counter

i need some help, can't seem to locate the problem, my program is supposed to take only octal digits and then count number of 4's and print that but the 4's counter doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char okt[6];
    int i, broj, brojac = 0;
    gets(okt);
    broj = strlen(okt);
    for (i = 0; i < broj; i++) {
        if (okt[i]>'7' || okt[i]<'0') 
            printf("Ucitani niz nije pravilno zadan ");
        else 
            if (okt[i] == 4) 
                brojac++;
    }

    printf("Znamenka 4 se pojavljuje %d puta %d", brojac);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give a sample of the input you're supplying, and the output you're getting.

Comment: You should _never_ use gets. You can't specify the maximal ammount of characters you read in and can get buffer overflows.

Comment: `printf` 2 `%d`s but only give one value?

Answer (score 3):

Should this `okt[i] == 4` be `okt[i] == '4'`?

Answer (score 1):

As you are comparing `char`, put single quote around `4`.

```
else if (okt[i] == '4') brojac++;
```

Also there are two `%d`s in the below statement expecting two int values. So your second `%d` will print `0`.

```
printf("Znamenka 4 se pojavljuje %d puta %d", brojac); <-- Expecting two integers
```